# Python lambda optimization

Tags: python, lambda

I've just been learning lambda (About time) and I've figured some things out, I get the general idea.

I have a map() with a lambda here that can surely be made shorter, but I don't know how:

```
map(lambda x: [ x.split()[0], x.split()[2], x.split()[4] ] , y)
```

I hoped it would be possible to get the 0, 2 and 4 elements of the split 'x' at once, but currently I have to split it 3 times to get them...

Comment: Note that you almost never actually want to use `map`; it's almost completely obsoleted by list comprehensions.  If you're reading a tutorial that's telling you to use it, it's probably very old and may be teaching you bad habits.  The clean way of writing this (starting from @Yuval's answer) is `[x.split()[0:5:2] for x in y]`.

Comment: Yes, but this is just me tinkering with lambda so for the purposes of learning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
lambda x: operator.itemgetter(0, 2, 4)(x.split())
```

Comment: I assume that's supposed to be `operator.itemgetter`?

Comment: @delnan: Pfft. Yes. That's what happens when I'm not awake.

Comment: I like both, but this one gives more control over which ones I want, is there a non-itemgetter() way to do it with the list syntax alone?

Comment: No. `list` does not support arbitrary sequences of indexes.

Comment: Shame, would there be any way to store x.split() and work from that?

Something like:
map(lambda x: z = x.split() [z[0], z[2], z[5]] , y)

Comment: `lambda` cannot be used for statements, and `map()` will only invoke the function once per element.

Comment: Could a second lambda be used to loop through the outcome of x.split()?

Comment: That turns the algorithm into O(m*n). You're better off caching the result of `operator.itemgetter()`.

Comment: I don't see how that is possible, if the x.split() was cached for the second lambda and you loop through it, it's essentially the same as itemgetter but without having to import operator...

Comment: `map()` will only invoke the function once per element. You'd have to call this other function yourself.

Comment: I see, so a loop withing a lambda is not possible in this context? Something like this?  
    map(lambda x: x.split()[(for z in (0, 2, 4): return z)] , y)

Comment: `list` does not support arbitrary sequences of indexes.

Comment: Sorry, guess I was thinking in bash.

Answer (score 4):

`map(lambda x: x.split()[0:5:2] , y)`

Meaning - take `x.split()` and take the sublist `[0:5]` with each second item in it.

Comment: `[0:4:2]` will only give the first two. Try `[0:5:2]`

Answer (score 1):

Just for variety's sake, featuring no `itemgetter()` call:

```
    map(lambda x: [x[i] for i in (0,2,4)], (s.split() for s in y))
```

The `(0,2,4)` could be replaced with `range(0,5,2)`, of course.
For such a small number of items you could just be explicit with: `[x[0], x[2], x[4]]`

How it works: The `lambda` function simply returns a list of the desired elements of the list it is passed. The `(s.split() for s in y)` is a generator that produces `split()` versions of the items in list `y`. Driving all this is the call to `map()` which applies the `lambda` function to each one of the `split()` items from `y`. In Python 2.x it creates a list of the results from each of these calls.

To answer your follow-up question in the comments about using `g = lambda x: [x[i] for i in (0,2,4)]`
along with `(g(s.split()) for s in y)` to get rid of `map()`. That's basically the right idea, but the second expression results in just a generator object. That would need to be wrapped in something like: `[g(s.split()) for s in y]` to get the result.

If you didn't want to have a separate `lambda` named `g` you could use:

```
    [(lambda x: [x[i] for i in (0,2,4)])(s.split()) for s in y]
```

Comment: Theres what I was looking for, but I don't see just how it works :/

Also, wouldn't this mean map() is only iterating once and that the for loop does the work? Can't we just get rid of map() somehow this way?

Comment: You said you wanted to use a `lambda` function, so something will have to call it and `map` is the obvious choice. If you don't want to use `lambda`, as @Glenn Maynard said, list comprehensions are the way to go.

Comment: What about something like: lambda x: [x[i] for i in (0,2,4)] (s.split() for s in y)

Comment: No, the result of that expression is just a `lambda` function: such as `<function <lambda> at 0x00AD44F0>`. Something else needs to call the function multiple times and collect the results. That's why `map()` is used.

Comment: Ok, I see... Is it possible to say: g = lambda x: [x[i] for i in (0,2,4)] then later on:  (g(s.split()) for s in y)